# Dimension of the skein module of a closed manifold?

Tags: knot-theory, quantum-field-theory, skein-relation

I'm looking for a reference to Witten's conjecture that the free part of the (Kauffman bracket) skein module of a closed 3-manifold is finitely generated, i.e. the dimension of $K(M)$, where $M$ is a closed manifold, is finite.

Was this conjecture stated in any paper?

Comment: I give this as a comment rather than an answer, since it's hearsay.  The story of this "conjecture" that I heard was that he asked a certain mathematician, whom I won't name to respect their privacy, whether it "mathematicians knew" that they were finite-dimensional (implying that he did).  This mathematician wasn't a skein module specialist, so forwarded the question to some skein theorists, and it made the rounds amongst them.  The case of T^3 was recently settled by Gilmer-Masbaum following Carrega (perhaps you know this?).